# Can Windows installer deploy an assembly based on the version of an external application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, interop, windows-installer, tlbimp

I am developing a small program (a dll) in Visual Studio 2010 / .NET 4 that integrates with an external application (we'll call it ExApp) through COM interop. I am generating the interop assemblies myself using `TlbImp.exe`, as none are provided by the external application. ExApp comes in three popular versions, each with an effectively identical API, but each having a different (and incompatible) generated interop dll. At the moment, that means I have three separate installers:

- Installer w/ `my.dll` built/linked against `Interop.ExApp.dll` v1
- Installer w/ `my.dll` built/linked against `Interop.ExApp.dll` v2
- Installer w/ `my.dll` built/linked against `Interop.ExApp.dll` v3

There must be a better solution than this.

How do I configure Visual Studio / Windows Installer so that I only need one install .exe? Meaning that the installer will detect the version of ExApp, and install the corresponding versions of `my.dll` and `Interop.ExApp.dll`.

And a bonus question: Since the ExApp API has not meaningfully changed, how can I compile one version of `my.dll` to work with any installed version of ExApp?

Comment: Late binding with the C# *dynamic* keyword or vb.net is an option in COM.  Failing that, the installer has to poke the registry to look for the CLSID key.  That's custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you build the interops with 3 different file names and then create a factory pattern in your application to decide which provider to use at runtime?

I could show you ways of searching the system to install one of 3 mutually exclusive files but I don't think that kind of complexity belongs in the installer.  And it would fall apart anyways if someone upgraded the application that you are creating the interop for.

Answer (score 1):

On your Project's References, is the dll's `Specific Version` set to True or False? you could try setting it to False if its set as True.

This obviously wouldn't prevent a newer version from breaking (API changes), but that appears to be the case currently anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow my.dll to pull a different version of Interop.ExApp.dll from the GAC. However, while testing this idea I found that Interop.ExApp.dll v1 works with ExApp v2, so that is helpful.

Comment: @ScottB I'm not sure what you mean, that should allow you to use your single DLL for all 3 versions as long as the API is the same. What errors are you getting if you put your dll (with Specific Version set to false) on those machines?

Comment: If I run my.dll compiled with Interop.ExApp.dll v1 (with specific version set to false) on a machine where only Interop.ExApp.dll v2 is installed into the GAC, my.dll fails with 'assembly not found'.